# How to check Pentaho kettle version from the command line?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I know I can check the Pentaho version by opening the spoon.sh in vi mode, but the Pentaho that is installed in production environment doesn't have that information in it. Probably some employee before me has edited it. 
So is there any other way that I can know the version of the Pentaho that is being used on the server?

Comment: you can also check the version of the kettle-core jar in the lib folder. Bit hacky that though :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the command line and type this command to see the version of kettle. Now your production server may a Linux box or a Windows box. Depending on the type of the platform, use the command below:

Linux:

```
./kitchen.sh -version
```

Windows:

```
Kitchen.bat -version
```

To check the version of the bi-server, just go to the Pentaho User Console (PUC). Help --> About.

Comment: [root@chq02-dwapp01-d data-integration]# kitchen.sh -version
-bash: kitchen.sh: command not found
[root@chq02-dwapp01-d data-integration]# kitchen.bat -version
-bash: kitchen.bat: command not found

Comment: Dont forget "./" if it is Linux based server.

./kitchen.sh -version

Comment: I just ran it and here's the output: "[pentahouser@pentaho-server.LEBANON data-integration]$ ./kitchen.sh -version /home/pentaho/pentaho/design-tools/data-integration DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/java/default/bin/java DEBUG: PENTAHO_INSTALLED_LICENSE_PATH=/home/pentaho/.pentaho/.insta‌​lledLicenses.xml 2016/10/17 14:10:28 - Kitchen - Kettle version 5.4.0.6-154, build 1, build date : 2015-11-09 08.54.47"

Comment: It is Linux based server and my permission is denied

Comment: [root@chq02-dwapp01-d data-integration]# ./kitchen.sh -version
-bash: ./kitchen.sh: Permission denied

Comment: That's the administration issue. Contact your system administrator to grant you the permission. But, the command I gave you, works perfectly. :)

Comment: or just enter $KETTLE_HOME/lib/ and look onto kettle-core-$VERSION_NUMBER____$BUILD_NUMBER.jar

Comment: @Nikhil: It's actually ./kitchen.sh. k is in the small case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out the version by logging into the Pentaho User Console. Then go to **Help** and click on **About**. There i can see the version number being used. This gives the version number for the Pentaho Bi Server.

For the Development tool. I have checked the logs for errors and got the version number there.